I am creating a personal finance tracker and I need a sort feature for that But I am getting confused with that
I need to implement a sort functionality where clicking on a column heading in the treeview table sorts the data based on that column. The sorting should toggle between ascending and descending order.
This is my sample code:
def sort_by_column(self, tree, col, reverse):
    # Collect data for each row
    data = [(tree.set(row, col), row) for row in tree.get_children()]
    # Sort the data based on the values
    data.sort(reverse=reverse)

    for index in range(len(data)):
        val, row = data[index]
        tree.move(row, '', index)

    tree.heading(col, command=lambda c=col: self.sort_by_column(tree, c, not reverse))

When I click between the columns it is working but the sorting is not correct.
I did many changes this is my final change. I cannot think of anything.

What do you mean by "the sorting is not correct"?

When I clicked on the ID coloumn It starts from 1 then goes from 10 to 19, then 2, then 20. The same thing happens in date and amount coloumn

It is because data retreived from treeview are all converted to strings.

Ok This is the code but i dont know what needs to be updated in the code

Since data retreived from treeview are all converted to strings, so the sorting result is not what you expect on numbers.
You can create a function to convert those numbers into float numbers and use this function as the sorting function:
def sorting(x):
    try:
        # if it can be converted to float number, return the float number
        return float(x[0])  # first item in x (a list/tuple) is used for sorting
    except:
        # otherwise just return whatever it is
        return x[0]

...

data.sort(key=sorting, reverse=reverse) # use the above function for sorting

